# Loading a block div Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, php-5.3

On the left of the page I have a list of links, they load a page in a div block is called "contained".

```
<div id="contenue"> </ div>.
```

In the head section and  I called the page file Js:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jabbax.js"></ script>.
```

For links must be of this type:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getPage('chargement_div/details.php','contenue');"> left box </ a>.
```

The link consists of following JavaScript function on the file containing the code Js Ajax, with a parameter, the name of the page, and name of the div block which will appear in the page.
loading the page `details.php` without reloading the entire page is working very well.
PROBLEM: the details.php page contains a JavaScript that is not displayed, in other words, only the html code is displayed in the div.

This is the content of detail.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var chartData = [ 
{country:"var1",litres:Math.round(<?php echo $pr_var1;?>)},
{country:"var2",litres:Math.round(<?php echo $pr_var2;?>)},
{country:"var3",litres:Math.round(<?php echo $pr_var3;?>)},
{country:"var4",litres:Math.round(<?php echo $pr_var4;?>)}];    
window.onLoad=function() {   
var chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.titleField = "country";
chart.valueField = "litres";
chart.depth3D = 10;
chart.angle = 12;
chart.labelRadius = -30;
chart.labelText = "[[value]]%";
chart.balloonText="[[title]] : [[value]]%"
chart.position = "center";    
var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
legend.position = "right";
legend.borderAlpha = 0.5;
legend.horizontalGap = 20;
legend.markerType = "circle";
legend.switchType = "x";   
chart.addLegend(legend);
chart.write("chartdiv");
}
</script>   
<div id="chartdiv" style="height:350px;position: relative;" ></div>
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure your echoing it? also the javascript wouldn't run if you just load it via ajax. not sure how to get it to run in plain javascript I use jQuery.Also if you dont need it to be ajax you can use a php include.

Comment: Use php include does not solve my problem.
I want to change the contents of the php page without reloading the whole page just the left div.

Comment: then in your php code sure your code is either echod or not in a php block. if your not familiar with herodoc and heredoc they are very useful ways of echoing code. you don't have to escape anything in them. additionally some people break out of php while in an if statement for echoing code. ie <? if(statement){ ?>html code<?php }else{ ?> more html code <?php } ?>